# JAVA: file:/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf (file not found)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, startup, filenotfoundexception

When I try to open an entry in my compiled .jar file, I get the following error (translated from german to english ;)):

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf (file not found)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
at application.ConnectionProperties.ReadConnectionProperties(ConnectionProperties.java:23)
at application.MainController.ReadConfigFile(MainController.java:218)
at application.MainController.initialize(MainController.java:68)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2548)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:2441)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3214)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3175)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3148)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3124)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.loadImpl(FXMLLoader.java:3104)
at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader.load(FXMLLoader.java:3097)
at application.Main.start(Main.java:15)
at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication1$163(LauncherImpl.java:863)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runAndWait$176(PlatformImpl.java:326)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$null$174(PlatformImpl.java:295)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$175(PlatformImpl.java:294)
at com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:95)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.gtk.GtkApplication.lambda$null$50(GtkApplication.java:139)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Starting application!

Here is the code:

```
private void ReadConfigFile() {
    try {           cp.ReadConnectionProperties(this.getClass().getResource("/ressources/db_config.conf"), dbhost1,
                dbport1, dbusername1, dbpasswd1, dbname1);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

and

```
public void ReadConnectionProperties(URL string, TextField dbhost1, TextField dbport1, TextField dbusername1, TextField dbpasswd1,TextField dbname1) throws IOException {
    String host, port, uname, password, name;
    /** */
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(string.getFile());
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);

    host = br.readLine();
    port = br.readLine();
    uname = br.readLine();
    password = br.readLine();
    name = br.readLine();

    dbhost1.setText(host);
    dbport1.setText(port);
    dbusername1.setText(uname);
    dbpasswd1.setText(password);
    dbname1.setText(name);

    br.close();
}
```

The Folder /ressources/ and the file db_config.conf existed in the .jar file and in the project. He show me only the error, when I want to start the jar. When I start the project in eclipse, he say me no error.

Please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message is correct: you do not have a file named `/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf` on your computer.  The [URL](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html) you obtained from [`Class.getResource()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-) refers to an entry inside a jar file.  It can not be read using `FileReader`.

You must use the [`URL.openStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream--) method to obtain an input stream from which you can read the contents of that entry.  Or use [`Class.getResourceAsStream()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream-java.lang.String-) to save a step.

When you ran your project in eclipse, the reason it did not fail is because the classpath entry that contained the file was a directory, and so the URL returned by `Class.getResource()` just happened to be a file on the local filesystem.  When you package your program in a jar file, then the resource you are looking for is inside a jar rather than a local file.  Using `URL.openStream()` will work in both situations.

```
public void ReadConnectionProperties(URL url, TextField dbhost1, TextField dbport1, TextField dbusername1, TextField dbpasswd1,TextField dbname1) throws IOException {
    String host, port, uname, password, name;
    /** */
    try ( final InputStream stream = url.openStream();
          final Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
          final BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(reader); )
        {
        host = br.readLine();
        port = br.readLine();
        uname = br.readLine();
        password = br.readLine();
        name = br.readLine();

        dbhost1.setText(host);
        dbport1.setText(port);
        dbusername1.setText(uname);
        dbpasswd1.setText(password);
        dbname1.setText(name);
        }
```

See also [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html).

Answer (score 0):

The clue is in the first line of the exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 
  file:/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf 
  (file not found)
```

That name is NOT a filename.  It is a URL.  You cannot use `FileReader(String)` to open a resource.  For a start, the resource you are trying to read is not a file.  It is actually a component of a file.

So lets have a look at the relevant parts of the code:

```
cp.ReadConnectionProperties(
    this.getClass().getResource("/ressources/db_config.conf"), ...);

public void ReadConnectionProperties(URL string, ...) throws IOException {
    FileReader fr = new FileReader(string.getFile());
```

The `getResource` call returns a URL which you then pass to your method.  I'm going to guess that the actual URL is a "jar:" URL.  Specifically:

```
jar:file:/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf
```

The method calls `URL.getFile()` ... but here's what the javadoc say about `getFile()`:

> Gets the file name of this URL. The returned file portion will be the same as `getPath()`, plus the concatenation of the value of `getQuery()`, if any. If there is no query portion, this method and `getPath()` will return identical results.

It you understand the URL specification, the "path" of *this* URL is everything after the first colon; i.e. `file:/tmp/guest-u9uIBd/Schreibtisch/Untitled.jar!/ressources/db_config.conf`

Then you attempt to use that "file:" URL as if it was a file pathname.

---

So what is the solution?  Well there are lots of them, but a simple one is:

```
cp.ReadConnectionProperties(
    this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/ressources/db_config.conf"), ...);

public void ReadConnectionProperties(InputStream is, ...) throws IOException {
    Reader r = new InputStreamReader(is);
```

(Note that the reader will read the resource using the platform default character encoding scheme.  That might not be the right thing to do.)